# How to divide polynomials in a modern algebra sense, in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: polynomials

I have an exercise in Childs' book "A Concrete Introduction to Higher Algebra", and there are five parts where polynomial long division is required. I do NOT want the answers, but I honestly just have no idea what they're asking. It seems really easy, but it can't be that easy. The exercise is as follows:

Find the quotient and remiainder when the first polynomial is divided by the second in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$:

$$1) x^2-7x-1;x-2$$

$$2) x^4-2x^2-1;x^2+3x-1$$

$$3) 2x^3-3x^2+1,x$$

$$4) x^2+x+1,2$$

$$5) 3x^2-x-1,x^2-2$$

These are really easy to do with basic arithmetic and long division of polynomials that's learned in a high school algebra course. How is this any different?? Could someone give me some insight, and MAYBE one solution to one of those so I can do the rest?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You write that “there are five parts where polynomial long division is required” and you claim that you know how to do long polynomial division. Then, what prevents you from using it to solve this problem?

Comment: see [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).

Comment: I just know this is an introduction to abstract algebra textbook, and I feel like just regular polynomial long division is too easy for this. I'm perfectly capable of calculating it. But I just don't understand what the new context is when we discuss polynomials as algebraic structures, and can use strategies such as the Chinese Remainder Theorem and others. I know how to do this. I just don't know why they're asking this and what the relevance is.

Comment: We're studying fields, rings, groups, etc at the moment, and these exercises that I posted are jumbled with several questions that are more related to modern algebra and more sophisticated than basic arithmetic.

Comment: I suppose the question is just: Is polynomial long division all that's required, or is there some deeper meaning I'm supposed to understand?  Perhaps some other method using the Chinese Remainder Theorem or some related corollaries introduced shortly before.

Comment: You don't have any wiggle room.  The requirement of "Find the quotient and remiainder when the first polynomial is divided by the second in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$" is **totally unambiguous**.  Therefore, you have **no choice** but to perform standard polynomial long division.

Comment: $$4) \quad x^2+x+1,2$$ $$quotient =\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2};\;remainder=0$$